# Generalization of the Tower of Hanoi?

Tags: algorithms, recursion, combinatorial-game-theory

What is the least possible number of steps for the Tower of Hanoi with $n$ discs and an arbitrary number $k$ of towers?

For example, Tower of Hanoi with $4$ towers, $5$ towers, etc.

Comment: Retagged this with 'algorithms' because this question is fundamentally about trying to find the most efficient  algorithm to generally solve the Tower of Hanoi puzzle.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure what to tag it.

Comment: Possible good paper to read at [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0631v1). Another [Wolfram Library](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4861/).

Comment: Hold on, the arbitrary number of $k$ tower refers to the number of spindles onto which you can place discs, right? Like, Tower of Hanoi with $n$ discs and $3$ towers is $2^n -1$.

Comment: Yes. $k$ refers to the number of spindles.

Comment: D.E.K on it at page 321: http://www.ams.org/notices/200203/fea-knuth.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interestingly enough, it seems that we don't actually know!

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#With_four_pegs_and_beyond):

> Although the three-peg version has a simple recursive solution as
>   outlined above, the optimal solution for the Tower of Hanoi problem
>   with four pegs (called Reve's puzzle), let alone more pegs, is still
>   an open problem.

There is, however, a presumed optimal solution for the puzzle with Four Spindles, also to be found in the same Wikipedia article.

Comment: I had heard that a generalization had been made for $k$ pegs, but I have not actually found it so I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 3):

The article by Demontis is totally flawed, for more details see https://doi.org/10.1142/S1793830919500496. In 2014 Thierry Bousch published a solution to The Reve's puzzle (four pegs version), see https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~bousch/preprints/revespzl.pdf. The FS conjecture for Tower of Hanoi with five or more pegs remains an open problem.

Comment: I have edited your answer to include the full links, rather than shortened links.  Shortened links are untrustworthy, as one cannot immediately see where they are being taken with a click---if you are worried about long URLs in your text, it is better to to use the syntax `[link descriptions](link url)`.

Comment: That being said, your answer is currently phrased as a "link only" answer, and risks deletion as such.  Answers on Math SE are meant to be as fully self-contained as possible; links to off-site resources violate that expectation.  While you are not expected to reproduce the entirety of the two linked papers, it would be good if you could give a more complete explanation of what is contained in those papers.

Answer (score 2):

The presumed optimal solution for four or more pegs, predicted by the [Frame-Stewart algorithm](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2304268?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) in 1941, has been recently proved optimal after about 80 years by Roberto Demontis in this 2019 paper [What is the least number of moves needed to solve the k-peg Towers of Hanoi problem?](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S1793830919300017) (you can find a free PDF [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3280)).